# Route solr/admin/info/system does not exies but given error RouteCollection Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have does not exist **"solr/admin/info/system"** but Laravel 5.5 given below error

```
There was an error occured on Heal Me.following are details of Error:<br><br>Request:GET /solr/admin/info/system?wt=json HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection:      close

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in 
/var/www/html/healme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:179
```

Where I found **"solr/admin/info/system"** this route or URL. How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Someone is just pinging your server, looking around for various components, in order let's say to introduce itself into your system without invitation ...
As you don't have any Solr install, Laravel is logging an invalide route.
So just don't bother about it, but assure yourself that the rest of your box is safe and up to date in its security packages... ;)